# ¿Cómo acceder a atributos de elementos HTML en typescript?

Tags: typescript

Estoy tratando de ***cambiar el valor de una serie de atributos de elementos HTML en typescript***. No encuentro la forma de acceder a ***href***, es decir el tipo del ***HTMLElement*** concreto.

Tengo este codigo donde me falta saber ¿por qué sustituyó Xxx?:

```
let image = document.getElementById(this.id_img) as HTMLImageElement;
let url   = document.getElementById(this.id_link) as Xxx;

image.src = this.imgs['mi-image.jpg'];
url.href  = this.urls['mipage.com/page-1'];
```

Answer (score 2):

El tipo necesario es ***HTMLAnchorElement***. Así el código quedaría:

```
let image = document.getElementById(this.id_img) as HTMLImageElement;
let url   = document.getElementById(this.id_link) as HTMLAnchorElement;

image.src = this.imgs['mi-image.jpg'];
url.href  = this.urls['mipage.com/page-1'];
```

Pueden encontrarse los "tipos" para acceder a los distintos atributos en la [Web API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API) de Mozilla, letra H.